# Form validation in formvalidation.io conflict between multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, formvalidation.io

I'm using formvalidation.io and I have 2+ forms on the same page.

When I submit form 1, the submit button is disabled if form 2 is not valid, even though form 1 is valid.

JS:

```
$('form').formValidation({
    framework: 'bootstrap',
    trigger: 'keyup blur',
    fields: {
        required: {
            selector: '[validator="required"]',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'This is required'
                }
            }
        }
    })
};
```

HTML:

```
<form id="form-1">
  <input type="text" validator="required">
  <input type="text" validator="required">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form id="form-2">
  <input type="text" validator="required">
  <input type="text" validator="required">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Nope. I ditched formvalidation.io completely now and wrote my own.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the proper id of your form:

```
<form id="form-1"></form>

$('#form-1').formValidation({
        ...
});
```

Ref: http://formvalidation.io/examples/cant-submit-form-after-validation/

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by making it all one form and using javascript to disable items and change the action of the form.

Answer (score 0):

this is old but I'm today on this :)

You can manually validate each form and submit it when form is valid.

More info - https://formvalidation.io/guide/examples/validating-form-manually/